# flickableItem.interactive не работает для TableView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

Почему для `ListView` `flickableItem.interactive: true` работает,
а для `TableView` нет? Что не так сделано?

```
TableView {
                anchors.top: rowTop.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.topMargin: getHeight(10)
                anchors.leftMargin: getWidth(10)
                anchors.rightMargin: getWidth(10)
                flickableItem.interactive: true


                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "title"
                    title: "Title"
                    width: 100
                }
                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "author"
                    title: "Author"
                    width: 200

                }

                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement {
                        title: "1"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "2"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "3"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "4"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "5"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "6"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "7"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "8"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "9"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "10"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "11"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "12"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "13"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "14"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "15"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "16"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "17"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "18"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "19"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "20"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "21"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "22"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "23"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "24"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "25"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "26"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "27"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "28"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "29"
                        author: "Gabriel"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "30"
                        author: "Jens"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        title: "31"
                        author: "Frederik"
                    }
                }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Потому что `ListView` наследует `Flickable`, а `TableView` наследует [ScrollView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html). Используйте функционал `ScrollView` для реализации требуемого Вами поведения